# Selector for dynamically generated ID

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a series of div where the id is tagged with the conventional:

```
<div id="result<%=order.ID %>">
```

The handler that submits the form can find out what order.ID is via:

```
fromInput.split(",")[1]
```

So how do i get that element concatenated with the static part of the DIV id?

```
$('#frmchooseOptions').ajaxSubmit({
    beforeSubmit: checkReady,
    target: "#result" + fromInput.split(",")[1]

});
```

mny thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the right idea but split the string wrong:

```
var divNum = fromInput.split(",");
divNum = DivNum[1];
```

then:
...

```
target: "#result" + divNum
```